# Make button same size as other controls

Tags: html, css

I have an input form in a table, since it is meant to allow entering multiple entries with identical fields. I can't get the button to remove the row to line up with the other controls in the row

```js
'use strict';

function addRecord() {
  const table = document.getElementById('records').tBodies[0];
  const tr = table.insertRow();
  let td = tr.insertCell();
  td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">';
  td = tr.insertCell();
  td.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="show" checked>';
  td = tr.insertCell();
  td.innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="removeRow(this)"></button>';
}

function removeRow(btn) {
  btn.closest("table").deleteRow(btn.closest("tr").rowIndex);
}

window.onload = (event) => {
  addRecord();
};
```

```css
th {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

button,
input {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
}

/* The checkbox styling was adapted from
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Advanced_form_styling#appearance_controlling_os-level_styling
*/
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  /* Adjusts the position of the checkboxes on the text baseline */
  vertical-align: -2px;
  color: white;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  content: "✔";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2em;
  right: 0px;
  top: -0.3em;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  /* Use `visibility` instead of `display` to avoid recalculating layout */
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <form method="get" id="form">
    <table id="records">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Show</th>
          <th>
            <button type="button" onclick="addRecord()">+</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hard time understanding ' I can't get the button to remove the row to line up with the other controls in the row'. Please add desired outcome.

Comment: You've hard coded the height and width of the checkbox, why not hard code the height and width of the button?   If you put a display of `flex` on the button it will align it's content vertically.  The check symbol itself, since it's pseudo element will not be constrained by the padding of the checkbox container, so you'll need to adjust the check characters size and position manually with your absolute positioning and font size.

Comment: @ScottZ I am new to modern CSS. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will move you in the direction you desire.  The Checkbox element has a hard coded height and width of 2em; so do the same for the button.

```
.button{
  height:2rem;
  width:2rem;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Adding those styles to the button should make it the same width and height of the check box element.  The `display:flex` will allow the content of the button the be vertically centered.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that and the button ended up much bigger than the checkbox

Comment: Hmm... Try using `rem` instead of `em`.  I think messing with the font-size is also affecting the em units.  I have updated my answer.